# VueJS - how to show different div on radio button select

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

How to show different component  on radio button select.

```
<input type="radio" name="book" value="One" checked="checked">
<input type="radio" name="book" value="Round">

      <div> // this should show show default, One is selected
        <p>Value One</p>
      </div>
      <div> // this should show show on radio change to Round selected
        <p>Value Round</p>
      </div>
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

How about something like this?

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    x: 'one',
  },
});
```

```html
<script src="https://rawgit.com/vuejs/vue/dev/dist/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <input type="radio" v-model="x" value="one">
  <input type="radio" v-model="x" value="two">
  
  <div v-show="x === 'one'">One</div>
  <div v-show="x === 'two'">Two</div>
</div>
```

Comment: i would replace v-show with v-if because in your case both components are created immediately. It is a minor problem in this scenario but with large components this could matter.

Comment: Awesome ! Thanks Thomas, as simple as that :P. if you wish please share the v-if for my future requirement.

Answer (score -1):

i have done it with javascript .onclick it calls each function which hides & show element vice versa

```js
function rdone(){
  document.getElementById('one').style.display ='block';
  document.getElementById('round').style.display ='none';
}
function rdround(){
  document.getElementById('round').style.display = 'block';
  document.getElementById('one').style.display ='none';
}
```

```css
#round{
display:none;
}
```

```html
<input type="radio" name="book" value="One" checked="checked" onclick="rdone();">
<input type="radio" onclick="rdround();" name="book" value="Round">

      <div id=one> // this should show show default, One is selected
        <p>Value One</p>
      </div>
      <div id=round> // this should show show on radio change to Round selected
        <p>Value Round</p>
      </div>
```

Comment: thanks for your suggestion but i was looking for specific to VueJS